# Numerically solve 2nd order differential equation with singularity

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, special-functions

Consider a second order differential equation with a potential that diverges at some generic value in the variable. For example:

$$-y^{\prime\prime}(s)+\frac1{\mathrm{cn}{(s\mid k^2)}}y(s)=0$$

where $\mathrm{cn}(s\mid k^2)$ is the `JacobiCN[s, k^2]` function. Now, suppose, the differential equation has to be solved on the interval of a full period, namely $s\in[0,2\mathbb{K}]$, where $\mathbb{K}$ is the complete elliptic integral of the first kind `EllipticK[k^2]`, with the initial conditions $y(0)=0$ and $y^\prime(0)=1$.

If I just naïvely start the `NDSolve` function for, say, $k^2=0.7$:

```
NDSolve[{-y''[s] + y[s]/JacobiCN[s, 0.7] == 0, y[0] == 0, y'[0] == 1},
  y[s], {s, 0, 2 EllipticK[0.7]}]
```

*Mathematica* rightfully complains that a singularity is detected at half of the evaluation range, namely at the value `s = EllipticK[k^2] = 2.07536`:

> NDSolve::ndsz: At s == 2.0753631352632516`, step size is effectively zero; 
>   singularity or stiff system suspected.

And also the resulting interpolating function terminates at this value:

```
{{y[s] -> InterpolatingFunction[{{0., 2.07536}},<>][s]}}
```

So, evidently, the solution does not overcome the point of singularity and is given only for the half of the required interval. I heard that there are numerical techniques to overcome singularities when solving differential equations. It makes me wonder that *Mathematica* does not activate these by default. What can I do to solve a differential equation beyond a singularity numerically in *Mathematica*?

Comment: [This documentation about events](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NDSolveWhenEvents.html) might be helpful.

Comment: (I'm not posting an answer since this is rather specific to the DE concerned.) You have a coefficient that is a Jacobi elliptic function, which makes [Picard's theory](http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9939-98-04668-1) applicable (in complete analogy to the use of Floquet theory for differential equations with trigonometric coefficients, e.g. Mathieu). You might have better luck with an analytic approach instead of piggishly persisting with crossing through a singularity.

Comment: I am not sure about the document on events yet.
But the file on Picard's theory is an interesting read. If I understand correctly, they prove a certain structure for the fundamental matrix of any elliptic differential equation. However, they assume that the complete set of eigenvalues is known. I do not know any eigenvalues for my system. I have the feeling that the treatment in the file is of great mathematical value in classifying things, but of little practical value in computing explicit solutions. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: One other possibility you can do if you're unable or unwilling to follow through with Picard analysis is to do a bit of ["pole-vaulting"](http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/S0025-5718-1980-0583495-8); that is, integrate along a path in the complex plane that avoids the poles of $\mathrm{nc}(u\mid m)$.

Comment: Do you know any special solution of this ODE?

Comment: J.M. your second comment sounds as if the Picard analysis is actually practically possible. Indeed in this case I lack the necessary skill to carry it out. But I am willing to learn! If you could direct me to an explicit treatment for some related differential equation, I will be happy to study it.

Comment: The actual problem which I am confronted with involves a much more complicated, but still strictly elliptic potential term than just $\text{nc}(u|m)$. But no special solution is known (to me) for the ODE involving the relevant potential.

Comment: I see, the think is that if you can use the transformation $Y(S)=\int F(s)\, ds,\ S= \frac{F(s)}{y}$ where $F$ a solution of the ODE you can reduce its order by one. But this is a reduction for this ODE and don't know if can be applied to your actual problem.

Comment: "pole-vaulting" sounds as a great idea! Even more so, since the task at hand demands the evolution of the ODE for one period, but just randomly specifies the starting point to be the origin. Since the equation is elliptic (doubly periodic) it is complex to begin with and does not even have to be analytically continued. So all I need to do, is shift the evaluation path a little in the fundamental parallelogram: start at $s=i\epsilon$ and propagate to $s=2\mathbb{K}+i\epsilon$ for some explicit small $\epsilon$. Is this correct?

Comment: "...involves a much more complicated, but still strictly elliptic potential term." - but you at least know where the poles might possibly be, yes? If so, your only job is to find a nice contour that avoids those nasty poles. In any event, if you want worked examples of Picard analysis, you might want to look up treatments of the well-studied [Lamé equation](http://dlmf.nist.gov/29).

Comment: Btw have you tried expressing your potential using theta functions?

Comment: I did not try theta functions yet. Can they give some benefit?

Comment: I will just quote 
"A powerful way of computing the twelve Jacobian elliptic functions for real or complex values of both the argument z and the modulus k is to use the definitions in terms of theta functions given in ..." 
as found in NIST Handbook of Mathematical Functions pg. 566

Comment: Re: theta functions, it may, it may not. Depends on what your actual coefficients look like. With Jacobi's functions, since they are expressible as simple ratios of the theta function, this works out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The the function `y` is the integral of a logarithmic singularity, so it is relatively easy to understand. The function `JacobiCN[s, 7/10]` is relatively flat near `s == EllipticK[7/10]`, so that the integral of its reciprocal can be approximated by a logarithm:

```
y[s]/JacobiCN[s, 7/10] ~= y0 / (jp (s - EllipticK[7/10]))
```

where `y0 ~= y[s]` at `s == EllipticK[7/10]` and `jp = D[JacobiCN[s, 7/10], s] /. {s -> EllipticK[7/10]}`.

> [image: Mathematica graphics]
>   *Plots of `JacobiCN[s, 7/10]` and the variation in its derivative. *
>
> ```
> GraphicsRow@{Plot[JacobiCN[s, 7/10], {s, s1, s2}, 
>    GridLines -> {{EllipticK[7/10]}, None}],
>   Plot[D[JacobiCN[s, 7/10], s] - (D[JacobiCN[s, 7/10], s] /. s -> EllipticK[7/10]) // 
>     Evaluate, {s, s1, s2}, WorkingPrecision -> $wp, 
>    GridLines -> {{EllipticK[7/10]}, None}]}
> ```

We integrate once to find `y[s]` when the integration stops just before the singularity at `s == s0`.  This is adjusted by integrating `y''[s] ~= y0 / (jp (s - EllipticK[7/10]))` to estimate `y[s]` at `s == EllipticK[7/10]`.

The threshold for switching to a linear approximate of `y[s]/JacobiCN[s, 7/10]` is set by solving `JacobiCN[s, 7/10] == eps` for a small positive `eps`.  This will yield two points `s1`, `s2`, before and after `EllipticK[7/10]` respectively.  We then integrate to estimate the change in `p[s] == y'[s]` over the interval `s1 < s < s2`.

The displacements of the points `s1 < s0 < s2` from `EllipticK[7/10], 6]` turn out to be

```
N[{s1, s0, s2} - EllipticK[7/10], 6]
(*  {-1.82574*10^-10, -1.78664*10^-12, 1.82574*10^-10}  *)
```

Here is the whole code:

```
$wp = 30;                             (* working precision ($)*)
  (* estimate y at singularity *)
{sol0} = NDSolve[
   {-y''[s] + y[s]/JacobiCN[s, 7/10] == 0, y[0] == 0, y'[0] == 1},
   y, {s, 0, EllipticK[7/10]},
   Method -> "StiffnessSwitching", 
   "ExtrapolationHandler" -> {Indeterminate &, 
     "WarningMessage" -> False}, WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision];
  (* data for slipping past singularity *)
eps = 1*^-10;                                                (* threshold for switching *)
jp = D[JacobiCN[s, 7/10], s] /. {s -> EllipticK[7/10]};      (* for lin. approx. *)
s0 = SetPrecision[y["Grid"] /. sol0 // Last // First, $wp];  (* end data of sol0 ($)*)
y0 = SetPrecision[y["ValuesOnGrid"] /. sol0 // Last, $wp];   (*   "  "   ($)*)
p0 = SetPrecision[y'["ValuesOnGrid"] /. sol0 // Last, $wp];  (*   "  "   ($)*)
s1 = InverseJacobiCN[eps, 7/10];                             (* interval for switching *)
s2 = InverseJacobiCN[-eps, 7/10];                            (*   "  "   *)
dy = Chop@NIntegrate @@                        (* estimate change in y to singularity *)
   N[{p0 + y0 (x Log[x] - x /. x -> EllipticK[7/10] - s)/jp, {s, s0, 
      EllipticK[7/10]}, PrecisionGoal -> 10, 
     WorkingPrecision -> $wp}, $wp]; 
dp = NIntegrate @@                             (* estimate mean p = y' to singularity *)
    N[{(y0 + dy) Log[Abs[s - EllipticK[7/10]]]/jp, {s, s1, 
       EllipticK[7/10], s2}, WorkingPrecision -> $wp}, $wp]/(s2 - s1);

  (* final integration *)
{sol1} = NDSolve[{
    y''[s] == Piecewise[{             (* switch p' = y'' at singularity *)
       {dp, s1 < s < s2}},              (* use average rate of change near singularity *)
      y[s]/JacobiCN[s, 7/10]],          (* default *)
    y[0] == 0, y'[0] == 1},
   y, {s, 0, 2 EllipticK[7/10]},
   Method -> "StiffnessSwitching", 
   "ExtrapolationHandler" -> {Indeterminate &, "WarningMessage" -> False},
   WorkingPrecision -> $wp];
```

Plot:

```
Plot[y[s] /. {sol1} // Evaluate, {s, 0, 2 EllipticK[0.7]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]